# Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, for-loop

Is it possible to have a `foreach` loop in PHP with multiple "index" variables, akin to the following (which doesn't use correct syntax)?

```
foreach ($courses as $course, $sections as $section)
```

If not, is there a good way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You might want to clarify. Are you trying to loop through a 2D array or 2 arrays?

Comment: Not sure how this would work? Can you explain a bit more what your doing? You could have a nested foreach or combine the array before iteration. Let us know what you're trying to do and we can help you do it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

to achieve just that result you could do

```
foreach (array_combine($courses, $sections) as $course => $section)
```

but that only works for two arrays

Comment: Note; if `$courses` are numerical strings, they will turned into integers.

Comment: Hopefully I'm not ressurcting a thread that is too dead. But, I'm trying to achieve the same thing, I had for a second, but I dind't think it worked, but it didn, but for the life of me can't remember the code I put in. I'm trying to have category and value go into the database.  foreach($_POST['category'] as $i => $category) 
 { 
   // Get values from post.
   $category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
   $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value'][$i]);

Comment: what if both array have different value

Answer (score 18):

If both the arrays are of the same size you can use a `for` loop as:

```
for($i=0, $count = count($courses);$i<$count;$i++) {
 $course  = $courses[$i];
 $section = $sections[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

TRY -

1)

```
<?php
$FirstArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$SecondArray = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

foreach($FirstArray as $index => $value) {
    echo $FirstArray[$index].$SecondArray[$index];
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

or 2)

```
<?php
$FirstArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$SecondArray = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

for ($index = 0 ; $index < count($FirstArray); $index ++) {
  echo $FirstArray[$index] . $SecondArray[$index];
  echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

You would need to use nested loops like this:

```
foreach($courses as $course)
{
    foreach($sections as $section)
    {
    }
}
```

Of course, this will loop over every section for every course.

If you want to look at each pair, you are better off using either objects that contain the course/section pairs and looping over those, or making sure the indexes are the same and doing:

```
foreach($courses as $key => $course)
{
    $section = $sections[$key];
}
```

Comment: I've used both the accepted answer and the `$courses as $key => $course` answer above successfully within Wordpress. The difference is that the accepted answer is limited to two custom fields whereas this answer allows any number of fields and is therefore more flexible.

Answer (score 4):

No, because those arrays may have other number of items.

You must explicitely write something like that:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($courses) && $i < count($sections); ++$i) {
    $course = $courses[$i];
    $section = $sections[$i];

    //here the code you wanted before
}
```

Comment: pre-execute your '$i < count(...' code and store it in a variable so that it's not executed on every iteration of the for loop. For large arrays this is significant savings.

Comment: I work with very large projects which work under high load and usually it really doesn't matter because single SQL query is 1000 slower than php count :). And if you have to work with VERY large arrays then there is something wrong with application design.

Comment: Using Count inside the parameters will result in a very expensive transaction.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is maybe one of the rare cases PHP's array cursors are useful:

```
reset($sections);
foreach ($courses as $course)
{
 list($section) = each($sections);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What would that do, exactly? Are `$courses` and `$sections` just two separate arrays, and you want to perform the same function for the values in each? You could always do:

```
foreach(array_merge($courses, $sections) as $thing) { ... }
```

This makes all the usual assumptions about `array_merge`, of course.

Or is it that `$sections` comes from `$course` and you want to do something for each section in each course?

```
foreach($courses as $course) {
    foreach($sections as $section) {
        // Here ya go
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
foreach($array as $b=>$c){

}
```