# foreach with three variables add

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

i want to use foreach function for 3 **variables**

i use this code in my page:

```
foreach (array_combine($online_order_name, $online_order_q) as $online_order_name1 =>
    $online_order_q1) {
    mysql_query("insert into .......
}
```

how can i do that like :

```
<?
foreach (array_combine($online_order_name, $online_order_q,$third_variable) as
    $online_order_name1 => $online_order_q1 => $third_variable2) { 
?>
```

thank you

Comment: What language is this? Looks like PHP.

Comment: Please do not run functions within a loop like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert into database 3 arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761197/how-to-insert-into-database-3-arrays)

Answer (score 6):

I guess this will solve your need:

```
<?php
$A=array(1,2,3);
$B=array('a','b','c');
$C=array('x','y','z');

foreach (array_map(NULL, $A, $B, $C) as $x) {
  list($a, $b, $c) = $x;
  echo "$a $b $c\n";
}
```

Comment: the "array_combine" function is build in ;)

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` does only the iteration over one iterator and offering one key and one value. That's how iterators are defined in PHP.

In your question you write that you need multiple values (but not keys, but I think this won't hurt). This does not work out of the box.

However, you can create an iterator that allows you to iterate over multiple iterators at once. A base class ships with PHP it's called [`MultipleIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php). You can then create your own `ForEachMultipleArrayIterator` that allows you to easily specify multiple keys and values per each iteration:

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = array('b0' => 'a', 'b1' => 'b', 'b2' => 'c');
$c = array('c0' => 'x', 'c1' => 'y', 'c2' => 'z');

$it = new ForEachMultipleArrayIterator(
    //    array keyvar    valuevar
    array($a,  'akey' => 'avalue'), 
    array($b,  'bkey' => 'bvalue'),
    array($c,  'ckey' => 'cvalue')
);

foreach($it as $vars)
{
    extract($vars);
    echo "$akey=$avalue, $bkey=$bvalue and $ckey=$cvalue \n";
}

class ForEachMultipleArrayIterator extends MultipleIterator
{
    private $vars;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $arrays = func_get_args();

        foreach($arrays as $set)
        {
            if (count($set) != 2)
                throw new invalidArgumentException('Not well defined.');
            $array = array_shift($set);
            if (!is_array($array))
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Not an array.');
            $this->vars[key($set)] = current($set);
            parent::attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
        }

    }
    public function current()
    {
        return array_combine(array_keys($this->vars), parent::key())
            + array_combine($this->vars, parent::current());
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HZ3jpO) - But if you've come that far, I'm pretty sure it's clear that what you want to do can be solved much easier by actually iterating over something else. The example above is basically the same as:

```
foreach(array_map(NULL, array_keys($a), $a, array_keys($b), $b, array_keys($c), $c) as $v)
{
    list($akey, $avalue, $bkey, $bvalue, $ckey, $cvalue) = $v;
    echo "$akey=$avalue, $bkey=$bvalue and $ckey=$cvalue \n";
}
```

So better get your arrays into the right order and then process them :)

See also: [Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157810/multiple-index-variables-in-php-foreach-loop).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with `array_combine` and `foreach`, because they operate specifically on key/value **pairs** in an associative array. PHP doesn't have tuples as a builtin data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0, $length = count($array1); $i < $length; $i++) {
    list($a, $b, $c) = array($array1[$i], $array2[$i], $array3[$i]);
    ...
}
```

You should think about a better array structure though that doesn't require you to pull information from three different arrays. Something like:

```
$orders = array(
    array('name' => 'Foo', 'q' => 'bar', 'third' => 'Baz'),
    ...
);
```