# How to insert into database 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, insert, foreach

i want to insert 3 arrays into database using "foreach" or something else

sql :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order` text NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL,
  `quantity` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1256 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

form :

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <p dir="ltr"><input type="text" name="order[]" size="20"></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><input type="text" name="price[]" size="20"></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" size="20"></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><br /></p>
    <p dir="ltr"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></p>
</form>
```

For 2 arrays i use :

```
foreach (array_combine($orders, $prices) as $order=> $price) {

}
```

i want to insert it like that :
ex:

1- order  -  price -  quantity

2- order  -  price -  quantity

3- order  -  price -  quantity

4- order  -  price  - quantity

5- order  -  price  - quantity

...

...

how can i edit to this code to insert 3 arrays

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows how to do that, but I'm not sure if your form actually returns arrays. You should do some input checking too, to see if the values are indeed arrays, and do all have the same number of items (`count` function).

Code below just creates an insert statement based on three arrays.

```
// Get the arrays and sanatize them. I use hard codes ones in this example.
$orders = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$prices = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$quantities = array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9);


$query = "INSERT INTO orders (order, price, quantity) VALUES";
$comma = "";

// Move the array cursor of all arrays to the beginning.
reset($prices);
reset($quantities);
foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    // Get values and sanatize.
    $order = mysql_real_escape_string($order);
    $price = (float)current($prices);
    $quantity = (int)current($quantities);

    // Add to query.
    $query .= "$comma\n('$order', $price, $quantity)";
    $comma = ",\n";

    // Move pointer (for $orders, the foreach does this).
    next($prices);
    next($quantities);
}

// Execute $query.
var_dump($query);
```

Comment: I see your edit, but that is what this code does, isn't it? Of course you should still execute the query and such..

Comment: i used your code, it's doing OK but i cant understant why the code dont insert to database, this part var_dump($query); is print evry thing is ok

Comment: Oh yeah, I just printed the query, but you actually need to execute it by calling `mysql_execute` or whatever database library you are using. I trust you know at least anything about working with MySQL and PHP?  Since you asked such a specific question, I assumed you knew the basics. If you do execute the query and nothing happens, use `mysql_error` or a similar function to get the last error. There might be a typo in the generated query.