# php - how to use multiple array in foreach

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [foreach with three variables add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748115/foreach-with-three-variables-add)

i have following code i want to use multiple array in foreach. please note that i need $yourSiteContent[] as it is.

```
foreach ($pieces as $id and $pieces1 as $id_date) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = array('permalink' => $id, 'updated' => $id_date);
}
```

as you can see i have two arrays ($pieces and $pieces1), please check a loop and let me know where i am doing mistake.

$pieces1 contains dates and $pieces contains urls.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the `and` syntax new? Am I somehow behind?

Comment: i don't know just get it from google...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me (unless I'm not up on the latest techniques). To wit, a `foreach` is usually `foreach($arr as $key => $val)`, so your syntax has a couple of problems. Was your Googled sample code pseudocode by chance?

Comment: Do the keys of `$pieces` and `$pieces1` match?

Comment: foreach only supports a single array. You cannot iterate two at the same time without workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming both $pieces and $pieces1 have the same keys you can do the following:

```
for (array_keys($pieces) as $key) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = 
        array('permalink' => $pieces[$key], 'updated' => $pieces2[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `for` loop and an indexer, then access each array.

Answer (score 0):

To keep to the foreach format you can also do it like (Assuming both $pieces and $pieces1 have the same keys):

```
$yourSiteContent = array();
foreach ($pieces as $key=>$value) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = array('permalink'=>$value,
                               'updated'=>$pieces1[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_combine()` to combine the two arrays into a single array, with one being used for keys and the other for values.

```
foreach (array_combine($pieces, $pieces1) as $id => $id_date) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = array('permalink' => $id, 'updated' => $id_date);
}
```

See [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) for more information.