# How to for-loop over two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [foreach with three variables add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748115/foreach-with-three-variables-add)

I'm new to PHP so bear with me.

I have a url with two variables like so:

```
 ?foo=1,2,3,4&bar=a,b,c,d
```

Both parameters will always have the same amount of elements. I need to loop through the amount of elements like so:

```
1a
2b
3c
4d
```

and on each iteration assign two variables for `foo` and `bar` value.

If this was javascript no problem, but I have no idea how to do this PHP. This is what I have:

```
$foo = strtok($rvar_foo,",");
$bar = strtok($rvar_bar,",");
while ( $foo ){
  # now how do I get the corresponding value for $bar?
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157810/multiple-index-variables-in-php-foreach-loop) ; [foreach with three variables add](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748115/foreach-with-three-variables-add)

Comment: there should also be tons of duplicates for the second part about how to use strtok or convert string to array by comma.

Comment: I'm trying strtok-ing right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$foo = isset($_GET['foo']) ?  explode(",", $_GET['foo']) :  array();
$bar = isset($_GET['bar']) ?  explode(",", $_GET['bar']) :  array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($foo); $i++) {
    echo $foo[$i] . $bar[$i] . "<br />";
}
```

Is this what you want?

Output

```
1a
2b
3c
4d
```

Comment: not sure. Trying. `Explode` sounds suspicious though ... :-)

Comment: @frequent `explode('delimiter', $string)` is like javascripts `string.split('delimiter')` function.

Comment: @frequent very funny ..... :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function my_function($a, $b)
{

    var_dump($a . $b );
    // Do something with both values.
    // The first parameter comes from the first array, etc.
}

array_map("my_function", explode(",",$_GET['a']), explode(",",$_GET['b']));
```

Comment: don't you think `$_GET['a']` needs to an array so it should be `array_map("my_function", explode(",",$_GET['a']), explode(",",$_GET['b']));`

Comment: Aw shoot, you're right. I forgot PHP doesn't automatically create arrays there. This is one of many reasons I don't use PHP :-)

Comment: +1 Nice one .. updated your code

Comment: Thanks Baba. I thought I remembered a way that PHP would interpret `$_GET` as an array, but I need to look into it.

Comment: everyone forgets once in a while can see you are `phyton` `c++` person

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [`array_combine`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). It creates an array from two arrays, using one array for the keys, the other array for the values.

```
$foo = explode(',', $_GET['foo']);
$bar = explode(',', $_GET['bar']);
$foobar = array_combine($foo, $bar);
```

This would result in `$foobar` using the values from `$foo` as its keys and `$bar` for the values.

Calling `print $foobar[1]` would result in `a` being printed to the output. (You can find a running example [**here**](http://codepad.org/92Q73Tpe))