# PHP, "Foreach" using 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [foreach with three variables add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748115/foreach-with-three-variables-add)

If I have 3 arrays of the same size, is it possible to use the costruct foreach() to cycle in the same time the 3 arrays?

ex.

```
$name contains names

$surname contains surnames

$address contains addresses.
```

Can foreach take elements [1], [2], [.....] in the same time, to print

```
$name[1], $surname[1], $address[1];

$name[2], $surname[2], $address[2];
```

and so on?

Comment: Please choose variable names wisely for fairy tale code (or example code as you will), `$1` is not a valid variable name :)

Answer (score 21):

SPL's [multipleIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) is designed for precisely this purpose

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array3));

foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    list($name, $surname, $address) = $value;
    echo $name , ' => ' , $surname , ' => ' , $address , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Would this automatically handle the case that the arrays didn't contain the same number of elements?

Comment: I'm interested in the same question. By the way, thanks, this seems what I was searching for.

Comment: Probably not, because of the list construct. If one of the arrays had two indexes I believe it would fail.

Comment: You can change the `MultipleIterator` constructor and pass in `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY` which will cause the loop to execute for each element in the longest of the arrays.  The default is `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL` which is will only run while *every* array has an element in the current slot.

Comment: Take a look at the optional flags for the array constructor - http://www.php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.construct.php = which shows how to match up the arrays by numeric or associative indexes

Comment: it perfectly worked for me Mark Baker, thank you so much, it solved my big problem

Comment: Awesome, it still works in PHP 7 and 8. So much thanks

Answer (score 7):

Assuming they are all the same length:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++) {
    echo "{$names[$i]}, {$surnames[$i]}, {$addresses[$i]}";
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use foreach to have more security

Comment: ... How does using foreach offer more security?.....

Comment: well, according to php.net, foreach was meant to be used with arrays...

Comment: Yikes.  OK.  Good luck to you.

Comment: Yes, but using a for loop and accessing the indexes of the array functions the same, and faster.

Comment: The most easy and logical way to deal with this situation is using *for* I could not see any considerable reason to stick with *foreach* in such case.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like that (if arrays have the same keys):

```
foreach ($name as $key => $value) {
    //use $name[$key], $surname[$key], $address[$key]
}
```

`$key` contains key in `$name` array

`$value` = `$name[$key]`

Comment: What is $value? I tried to read the php.net documentation but I couldn't understand that part.

Comment: Pleae look at answer again.

Comment: oh thanks, it wasn't there the first time :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach($arr1 as $i => $val) {
    var_dump($val, $arr2[$i], $arr3[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array keys are the same you can use `key()` function.

But you can pass the key to `foreach($array as $key => value()){}`
This way you can refer to the key by the variable without using a function.