# Multiple array echo with foreach statement in php

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157810/multiple-index-variables-in-php-foreach-loop)

Can we echo multiple arrays using single `foreach` statement?

Tried doing it in following way but wasn't successful:

```
foreach($cars, $ages as $value1, $value2)
{
    echo $value1.$value2;
}
```

Comment: That would be nice to be able to do, but I think you're going to need to use indexes.  Are the arrays always the same length?

Comment: @Yzmir arrays are of different lenght.

Comment: If they are different lengths, this doesn't really make sense to do anyway.

Comment: You have to be very careful with trying to foreach over two arrays here. For instance, what happens when you try to sort the $cars array by car brand? In that case, the $ages array becomes useless. I think the best way to go, is to have a single array filled with some sort of CarAge objects and foreach over that array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

assuming both arrays have the same amount of elements, this should work

```
foreach(array_combine($cars, $ages) as $car => $age){
    echo $car.$age;
}
```

if the arrays are not guaranteed to be the same length then you can do something like this

```
$len = max(count($ages), count($cars));
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
    $car = isset($cars[$i]) ? $cars[$i] : '';
    $age = isset($ages[$i]) ? $ages[$i] : '';
    echo $car.$age;
}
```

if you just want to join the two arrays, you can do it like this

```
foreach(array_merge($cars, $ages) as $key => $value){
    echo $key . $value;
}
```

Comment: Wow you beat me. Also your code is exactly the same as mine :D -- +1

Comment: Using `array_combine()` won't work because the arrays are not the same size according to the person asking the question.  `array_combine()` will return `FALSE` when the arrays are not the same size.  Perhaps you could pad the smaller array?

Comment: I like your edit to handle different length arrays better than my Answer.  +1