# How to show my 2 variables together?

Tags: php, variables

i'm working on a parser to scrap all the prices of a categorie.(i work with simple_html_dom lib) I want to show the result as:

ProductName1
Price

---

ProductName2
Price

---

etc...

I have this:

```html
        $prices = $html->find('.price_container');

        $titles = $html->find('.s_title_block');
        
        foreach ($prices as $price) {
            echo 'Precio <br>';
            echo $price->innertext;
            echo '<hr><br>';
        }
        
        foreach ($titles as $title) {
            echo 'Nombre Producto <br>';
            echo $title->innertext;
            echo '<hr><br>';
        }
        
        $products = $title . $price;

        foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo $product->innertext;
        }
```

It's okay, i have the prices, and the titles, but... It show separately, and i need to show it together..

The result i have with the code i have pasted below is something like that:

Precio 
22,50 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
27,00 €

Precio 
27,00 €

Precio 
27,00 €

Precio 
19,50 €

Precio 
27,00 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
22,50 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
27,00 €

Precio 
25,50 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
27,01 €

Precio 
22,50 €

Precio 
30,00 €

Precio 
27,00 €

Precio 
22,50 €

Precio 
25,50 €

Precio 
24,00 €

Precio 
19,00 €

Nombre Producto 
ProductName1

Nombre Producto 
ProductName2

Nombre Producto 
ProductName3

Nombre Producto 
ProductName4

Nombre Producto 
ProductName5

Nombre Producto 
ProductName6

---

As i have asked, i need to show like that:

ProductName1
HisPrice

ProductName2
HisPrice

ProductName3
HisPrice

Thank you for your help it will be very apreciate.

Best regards

Comment: `$prices` and `$titles` have same length?

Comment: What about `array_merge()` function?

Comment: Sorry @JigarShah i don't understand your question.. $prices is a value number and $titles is the Name of the product

Comment: if both array have same number of records then you can easily do this with simple `for` loop.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110487/multiple-array-echo-with-foreach-statement-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the data in temporary variables and then use them, for example:

```
<?php
$tmpPr = [];
$tmpTi = [];

$prices = $html->find('.price_container');
$titles = $html->find('.s_title_block');

foreach ($prices as $price)
    $tmpPr[] = $price;
foreach ($titles as $title)
    $tmpTi[] = $title;

// let's suppose that the amount of prices and titles are the same
$cant = count($tmpPr);

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
    echo $tmpTi[$i],' ',$tmpPr[$i];
// NombreProducto.' '.Precio
?>
```

Comment: Really good idea, but when i run it it show me an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 29

Comment: Ahh my mistake, I forgot the `;` at the end of the line

Comment: Hello Matías, it's almost done. 

The result with your advise is this one:

ProductName

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba.php on line 30
Array

What can i do to solve the error with the string conversion? 

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello and sorry again, my mistake, I forgot to put the `[$i]` at `$tmpPr[$i]`, tell me if it does work now

Comment: Hello Matias, is working good, the only error is picking and associate the wrong's prices to products.