# php: foreach() how to assign to two variables

Tags: php, foreach

```
function example()
{

    foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {       # \__ both should run parallel
    foreach ($vtitles as $keystwo => $vtitle) {   # /

        $options .= '<option value="'. check_plain($key) .'" title="' . $vtitle . '"' . $selected  
.'>'. check_plain($choice) .'</option>';


    } // end of vtitle    
    } // end of choice

    return $options;
}
```

**Answers to some of the below questions and what I am trying to achieve.**

1. Array `$choices` is not numerically indexed.
2. Array `$vtitle` is numerically indexed.
3. They won't be shorter than each other as I have code which will take care of this before this code runs.
4. I am trying to return `$options` variable. The issue is that `$choices[0]` and `$vtitle[0]`  should be used only once. Hope I was able to express my problem.
5. I do not want to go through the `$vtitles` array once for each value in `$choices`.

@hakre: thanks I have nearly solved it with your help.

I am getting an error for variable `$vtitle`:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array    
instead in ArrayIterator->__construct() (line 35 of /home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/chatter/sites
/all/themes/kt_vusers/template.php).
```

I am sure its an array  this is the output using `print_r`

```
Array ( [0] => vishalkh [1] => newandold )
```

What might be going wrong ?

The below worked for me , thank you hakre

```
while
(
(list($key1, $value1) = each($array1))
&& (list($key2, $value2) = each($array2))
)
{
printf("%s => %s, %s => %s \n", $key1, $value1, $key2, $value2);
}
```

Comment: Are your arrays numerically indexed?

Comment: What will happen if one array is shorter then the other ?

Comment: Defining `$key` twice will certainly cause problems.

Comment: PHP doesn't work like that. What would you expect if `count($arrA)` == 5 and `count($arrB)` == 50?

Comment: [Do not sign your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: We need to know what you intend to do with this. Do you want to go through the $vtitles array once for each value in $choices? Are you trying to go through them at the same time, are they linked by their $key values ($choices[$key] is related to $vtitles[$key])?

Comment: @michael: $choices is not while $vtitles is  numerically indexed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not work the way you outline with your pseudo code. However, the SPL offers a way to iterate multiple iterators at once. It's called [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/MultipleIterator) and you can attach as many iterators as you like:

```
$multi = new MultipleIterator();
$multi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array1));
$multi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array2));

foreach($multi as $value)
{
    list($key1, $key2) = $multi->key();
    list($value1, $value2) = $value;
}
```

See it in action: [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bcOIJ7)

**Edit:** The first example shows a suggestion from the SPL. It has the benefit that it can deal with any kind of iterators, not only arrays. If you want to express something similar with arrays, you can achieve something similar with the classic `while(list()=each())` loop, which allows more expressions than `foreach`.

```
while
(
    (list($key1, $value1) = each($array1))
    && (list($key2, $value2) = each($array2))
)
{
    printf("%s => %s, %s => %s \n", $key1, $value1, $key2, $value2);
}
```

[Demo (the minimum number of elements are iterated)](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ouFCZE)

---

See as well a related question: [Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157810/367456)

Comment: I was not aware of this... interesting.

Comment: What if the arrays aren't the same size?
Would one key be null while the other has a value?

Comment: @crush: The default behaviour is that it will only iterate over valid pairs, e.g. if one array has two members, and the other has 10, it would only iterate over the first two pairs. But you can change that with flags, see the link to the PHP manual. - [`MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY` Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VYfbBw) (Yes, `NULL`).

Comment: Awesome. That's +1 worthy. Now the question is the overhead worth it haha.

Comment: @hakre I am using ur suggestion with spl but I am getting a error . I have updated my post with the error. What might be going wrong ? , thanks

Comment: @vishal: To better say what's going wrong you need to post more of your new code. Basically the error message means that the variable passed to the constructor is wrong but your print_r says it's an array which would be fine. So it's hard to say from the information given. Showing more code might reveal the culprit. You can put it on codepad viper as well where I posted the working demos, it's nice for testing smaller chunks of code.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do it in foreach loop in general case. But you can do it like this in PHP5:

```
$obj1 = new ArrayObject($arr1);
$it1 = $obj1->getIterator();

$obj2 = new ArrayObject($arr2);
$it2 = $obj2->getIterator();

while( $it1->valid() && $it2->valid())
{
    echo $it1->key() . "=" . $it1->current() . "\n";
    $it1->next();

    echo $it2->key() . "=" . $it2->current() . "\n";
    $it2->next();    
}
```

In older versions of PHP it will be like this:

```
while (($choice = current($choices)) && ($vtitle = current($vtitles))) {       
    $key_choice = key($choices);
    $key_vtitle = key($vtitles);
    next($choices);
    next($vtitles);
}
```

Comment: this would only work if both arrays had the same number of elements wouldn't it?

Comment: it depends on what the author wants

Comment: @alex347: I somewhat went into the same direction in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9299764/367456): First an example based on iterators, and then a second one based on `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer, no.

What you can do instead is:

```
foreach ($array1 as $k => $v)
    performMyLogic($k, $v);

foreach ($array2 as $k => $v)
    performMyLogic($k, $v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to refigure your logic to do what you want.  Any reason you can't just use 2 foreach loops?  Or nest one inside the other?

EDIT:  as others have pointed out, if PHP did support what you're trying to do, it wouldn't be safe at all.. so it's probably a good thing that it doesn't :)

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are the same, you can do this:

```
foreach ($choices as $key => $choice) {
    $vtitle = $vtitles[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
//get theirs keys
$keys_choices = array_keys($choices);
$keys_vtitles = array_keys($vtitles);

//the same size I guess
if (count($keys_choices) === count($keys_vtitles)) {

    for ($i = 0;$i < count($keys_choices); $i++) {

        //First array
        $key_1 = $keys_choices[$i];
        $value_1 = $choices[$keys_choices[$i]];

        //second_array
        $key_2 = $key_vtitles[$i];
        $value_2 = $vtitles[$keys_vtitles[$i]];

        //and you can operate
    }
}
```

But this will work if size is the same. But you can change this code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use two foreach loops.

```
foreach ($choices as $keyChoice => $choice)
{
    foreach ($vtitles as $keyVtitle => $vtitle)
    {
        //Code to work on values here
    }
}
```

Comment: True, I guess the question is really what is the intent of the example code?

Comment: I tried this earlier but I can't use this. As I have code inside which goes wrong then. Is there some other way ?

Comment: @vishal Check my comment on the question itself and edit the question to clarify and we can give you a better answer. We need to know what you are trying to accomplish with the for each loop.