# Attempting to loop through 2 arrays simultaneously

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157810/multiple-index-variables-in-php-foreach-loop)

I am trying to create a before and after image display using mysqli, php and html.
I am pulling the records from the db with mysqli and php, and am trying to view the results in an Unordered List using a foreach loop.

I have my 2 arrays which are created above in a while loop of a mysqli query. The array will only contain 5 results (for pagination, may change later).

```
$before_array[] = '
<div class="highslide-gallery">
<li>
<a href="'.$beforeurl.'" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="'.$beforeurl.'" width="100px" height="125px" alt="Highslide JS">
</a>
</li>';

$after_array[] = '
<li><a href="'.$afterurl.'" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)">
<img src="'.$afterurl.'" width="100px" height="125px" alt="Highslide JS">
</a>
</li>';
```

and in the view of the page I have the following code to display the before and after pictures.

```
<div id="hoverwrap">
<ul class="hoverbox">;

<?php 
foreach ($before_array as $value) {
    echo $value; 
 }

foreach ($after_array as $value) {
  echo $value;
}
?>

</ul>

</div><!-- end of hoverwrap div-->
```

With the current code it is displaying the pictures :
before - before - before - before - before - after - after - after - after - after.

Where I would like it to diplay:
before - after - before - after etc etc.

I was thinking a while loop but no matter which way I try and implement it, it results in a similiar display.
Any help or pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do that with one array, just concatenate the string. Apart from that, looping over tow arrays at once has already been asked (and answered) multiple times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop will do the trick here:

```
$x = count($before_array);
for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    print $before_array[$i];
    print $after_array[$i];
}
```

Why can't you print it in the mysql loop itself?

Comment: You Sir are a genius. Thanks heaps, have been messing around with this for a while now :) I was trying to seperate as much php logic and displaying - html as possible, just makes it easier to read what is happening with the pages. Thanks again