# PHP foreach in TinyMCE

Tags: php, html, html-email

I have an email (html) template loaded from db, which contains `foreach` loop (or may be some other PHP operation), to dynamically load/process content of API response.

```
$content = html_entity_decode($template); //$template loaded from db
```

**$content's html**

```
<p style="text-align:center">Hi {name},</p>
<p style="text-align:center">This is header</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($response as $item){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $item['img']; ?>" atl="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['qty']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Response of API**

```
$response = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'abc',
        'img'  => 'linkToImg',
        'price'=> '12',
        'qty'  => 10
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'xyz',
        'img'  => 'linkToImg',
        'price'=> '15',
        'qty'  => 2
    ),
);
```

Before sending email, I replace token using `str_replace('{name}', $name, $content);` , But I have no idea, how can i execute the `foreach` (or may be some other PHP operation) of $content to populate all dynamic data of $response and then send email.

**My Try**

I tried using token for $response as well, but,that approach is not good if I need multiple designs of $template and multiple response of API (for other purpose email).For example, in this template, I have Table for products but in other template i need `<ul> <li>` with inline `style` for listing some features etc.

Please suggest me how to achive this.

PS: I am using TinyMCE in frontEnd to design email template and store in DB.

Comment: You asked this yesterday, but them you included some more info, can you add that again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

In short, I need to use **Output Buffering**  e.g. ob_start();

**Explanition**

Step 1: I store the template in `.html` file.

Step 2: After the response from API, put `ob_start();`

Step 3: Include template using `include('path/to/file.html')`

Step 4: Get the output of buffer and send as Email Message.

**My Code**

```
//Consider HTML template in question is saved as template.html

//Response from API 
$response = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'abc',
        'img'  => 'linkToImg',
        'price'=> '12',
        'qty'  => 10
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'xyz',
        'img'  => 'linkToImg',
        'price'=> '15',
        'qty'  => 2
    ),
);

ob_start();
include('path/to/template.html');
$message = ob_get_clearn();

//now use $message in sending email
$this->emnail->message($message);
```

`ob_start()` will turn on the Buffer and hold the output of HTML, execute the PHP inside it and then `ob_get_clean()` return the output to $message and clean the buffer.

**Benefit**

By this approach, I can use **any** html template in `sendEmail()`. I only need to design Email Templates, rest thing will be done by `Output Buffer`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that you want to add more information/data to your email template.

---

**Solution #1**
Assuming that the  "**$content**" have the same message you want to include in your template you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$content = " Thank You!!!";   // some data
foreach($response as $item){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $item['img']; ?>" atl="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['qty']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $content; ?></td>  // just add the variable.
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

---

**Solution #2**: Assuming that the **$content** itself is an array then you might wanna  use :

```
foreach (array_combine($courses, $sections) as $course => $section)
```

Check the post for more details on foreach loop on multiple arrays: [Multiple index variables in PHP foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157810/multiple-index-variables-in-php-foreach-loop)
hope it helps